# How to install systemd on Bananian 15.08

Tags: systemd

Bananian 15.08 is based on Debian Jessie but still uses sysvinit instead of systemd.
How to disable SysVinit and switch to systemd?

Answer (score 2):

Remove file that blacklists systemd:

```
rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/systemd
```

Install systemd:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install systemd dbus systemd-sysv
reboot
```

Remove SysVInit:

```
apt-get remove sysvinit
```